# Why won't position:sticky; work

Tags: css, woocommerce

I'm working on a checkout page in Woocommerce that is divided in two halves. A form on the left and an overview of the order on the right. I set the overview to `position:sticky;` so it would scroll down as you fill in the form.

I actually have a couple different pages that have elements with `position:sticky;` which work perfectly fine so I can't figure out why I can't get it to work here. The only difference is the `<h3>` in between the columns and the `<form>` wrapper.

```css
form.checkout {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.checkout:before,
.checkout:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.col-1 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

h3 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.col-2 {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
}
```

```html
<form class="checkout">
  <div class="col-1"></div>
  <h3>Overview</h3>
  <div class="col-2"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

your div is sticky,

check this out

```
form.checkout {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yto9uj32/

Comment: I tried adding a fixed height like that but that changed nothing. But just for the heck of it I tried adding a fixed height to the first column which made the sticky position for .col-2 work. However this also added a scrollbar to the wrapper which shouldn't happen because I made sure not to add any overflows that messes with the height.

Comment: I found it.. a div 2 parents up has an overflow:auto; which messes up the sticky position of col-2. No idea why it skips 2 parent divs (first a <form> then a <div>) though. I found it after messing with the height so thanks for the suggestion @StaverVasile